# Record filtering doesn't return all records

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JS code that filters the records of a table, the problem is that the table has a specific amount of records (5 records per page) and when I do a filtering test, only the records of the selected pagination are filtered. that records from other pagination pages don't show up unless I change the pagination page.

```
var filter = document.getElementById('name_client');
var table = document.getElementById('search_client');

filtro.onkeyup = function() {
    var filterName = filter.value.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        var content = table.rows[i].cells[1].innerText;
        var corresponds = content.toLowerCase().indexOf(Filtername) >= 0;
        table.rows[i].style.display = corresponds ? '' : 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="contained">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mt-2">
         <div class="card">
            <nav class="navbar bg-light">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                  <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                     <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search client" id="name_client" aria-label="Search">
                  </form>
               </div>
            </nav>
         </div>
         <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table" id="table">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>ID</th>
                     <th>Nome</th>
                     <th>Actions</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  @foreach($clients as c)
                  <tr>
                     <td>{{ $c->id }}</td>
                     <td>{{ $c->name }}</td>
                     <td>
                        <form action="{{ url("delete/".encrypt($c->id)) }}" method="POST">
                        <a href="{{ url("update/".encrypt($c->id)) }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrows-rotate"></i>&nbsp;Update</a>
                        {{ ' ' }} {{ method_field('DELETE') }} {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Deletr</button>
                        </form>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
               </tbody>
            </table>
            {{ $clients->links() }}
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How to solve it problem?

Comment: Elements from the second pagination page onwards were supposed to be filtered to the first pagination page.

Comment: That's the way pagination works in a browser - the browser only holds those records for the current page. The common solution is to send the request to the serve so the server can filter all records.

Comment: You could resolve this by using something like `DataTables` jQuery plugin and server-side processing. More about it [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side).